# How do I append a second git repository?

Tags: git, repository

I have one git repository which is unavailable.

I want to create a fresh git repository (`git init`), and be able to append it when the first becomes available.

There will be no edit conflicts; the first repository is not being used.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why init a new repository instead of using a second upstream ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, just change the origin in the local git config. Switch back to the original and push into the changes which have occurred since you left.

```sh
git config --local --edit
```

After you initialize the new repository and push up the current code.

Comment: Both will be on-disk local repositories with no internet access; is it still possible then?

Comment: One can setup local repositories in conjunction with remote repositories, yes.